# Hide the tabBar in Rubymotion

Tags: rubymotion

I am building an iOS app in Rubymotion. I want to create a custom tabBar so I need
to use a real tabBar but hide it. How can I hide the tabBar in Rubymotion?

Answer (score 2):

To hide the tab bar you can use hidesBottomBarWhenPushed. 
The Objective C is:

```
MyController *myController = [[MyController alloc]init]; 
myController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
[myController release];
```

Therefore the RubyMotion Code is

```
@my_controller = MyController.alloc.init
@my_controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController.pushViewController(@my_controller, animated:true)
```

I hope this helps.  If you'd like to see more references to tab bars please check:
https://github.com/IconoclastLabs/rubymotion_cookbook/tree/master/ch_2/12_tabbars
Or if you'd like to see basics of navigation controller please check 
https://github.com/IconoclastLabs/rubymotion_cookbook/tree/master/ch_2/11_navbarbuttons

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this and it did not hide the tabBar: second_controller = SecondController.alloc.init
    second_controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

Comment: Do you have your code on github or somewhere where I can work with it more?